# KnockoutJS & jQuery(noConflict) & prototype.js = conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, knockout.js

So far, I've been using knockoutJS and jQuery without any issues, however merely including the prototype.js file in my html, leads to several errors upon launching the app. I  run jQuery.noConflict() at the start to avoid the conflict between jQuery and prototypejs, but apparently it doesn't solve the issue. Code and erros are as follows:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-contextmenu.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery.noConflict();   
</script>

<!--  knockout library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

//////////////

currentServerTree[key].serverName is not a function
anonymous()knockout-1.2.1.js (line 11)

```js
Za(a=" { text: scoringFunctio...n = __ko_value; } } } ", b=Object { preferenceName=d(), selectedServer=d(), selectedDatabase=d(), more...})knockout-1.2.1.js (line 11)
J()knockout-1.2.1.js (line 44)
j()knockout-1.2.1.js (line 34)
j(e=function(), d=null, b=Object { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved=textarea#inScoreFunction.inputField, read=function(), disposeWhen=function()})knockout-1.2.1.js (line 36)
J(e=textarea#inScoreFunction.inputField, d=null, b=Object { preferenceName=d(), selectedServer=d(), selectedDatabase=d(), more...}, a="data-bind")knockout-1.2.1.js (line 45)
ua(a=textarea#inScoreFunction.inputField)knockout-1.2.1.js (line 45)
g(a=[input#singleTable.inputField Constant, input#joinTable.inputField Variable, th, 16 more...], b=function())knockout-1.2.1.js (line 8)
ua(e=Object { preferenceName=d(), selectedServer=d(), selectedDatabase=d(), more...}, d=table#attributesTable4)knockout-1.2.1.js (line 45)
()index.jsp (line 1052)
[Break On This Error]   

...rn "+a))();return(new Function("sc","with(sc) { return ("+a+") }"))(b)},Fa:funct...
```

If I remove the prototype.js line, everything runs just fine. Any idea what could be causing the problem? Thank you!

Comment: You really shouldn't use minified libs during development. And why do you need prototype when you already have jQuery?!

Comment: I was given some pre-written prototype code that I was asked to implement within the app (which had supposedly been finalized, hence the minifieds), would rather not have to convert to jQuery, although I assume it would be possible.

Comment: Do you use jQuery?  Do you use $ anywhere?  What is currentServerTree?

Comment: Yes, I do use jQuery. I have eliminated all instances of '$' and replaced them with 'jQuery'. currentServerTree is a var to which a knockout observable is assigned

Comment: The error makes it sound like serverName is either not set or it is not an observable and you are either calling serverName() in your code or the binding is...  I don't know why that would have anything to do with prototype/jquery unless some Ajax call is updating your model and not mapping it to an observable.  A more thorough example would help...

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of noConflict() is to remove the "$" symbol from jQuery, thus allowing prototype to use it instead. In order for it to work, you must run it before Prototype actually loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-contextmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>

<!--  knockout library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries               However, you can override that default by calling jQuery.noConflict() at any point after jQuery and the other library have both loaded.  Thank you for the reply but it doesn't work, and it's the opposite of what the above link suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be actually using jQuery somewhere in your code, and trying to use `$` to access it.  Your call to `jQuery.noConflict();` doesn't actually do anything because prototype is loaded later.  It's purpose is to set $ back to what it was before jQuery changed it, so if you had loaded jQuery after prototype, it would set $ back to prototype.

It looks like you are not using prototype yet since the page works when it is not loaded, so try leaving the reference to prototype in there and change your .noConflict script after it to this just to see if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $ = jQuery;   
</script>
```

If that works then your code uses $ somewhere and you need to decide if you want $ to represent jQuery or prototype.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Tried to load jquery, then load prototype, then run the code you suggested, and got $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

element = $(element);   along with the previous errors